# Nginx.conf redirect to www and https simultaneously

Tags: nginx, configuration

I've been playing around with my site's conf file (nginx) with little success. All I want to do is when people type "example.com" or "http://example.com" in the address bar for it to automatically redirect them to "https://www.example.com".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in the nginx config file for your site. If you are on Ubuntu, this file is likely located at something like `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Once you have update the config file, be sure to test and restart NGINX using `sudo nginx -t && sudo service nginx reload`